# Правильно ли задавать значение .hover один для всех элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**$arr** - массив с **четырьмя DOM элементами** `<a>`, к которым будем применять **hover**, для прослушки событий при наведении на эти элементы.

---

Первый вариант:

```
for (var $i_nav = 0; $i_nav < 4 ; $i_nav++) {
    $arr[$i_nav] = $nav_conteiner.children('li').children('a').eq($i_nav).attr('id', 'id_nav' + $i_nav);

    $($arr[$i_nav]).hover(
         function () {

         },
         function () {    
         }
   );

}
```

---

Второй вариант:

```
$("#id_a_element_1").hover(
         function () {
         },
         function () {    
         }
   );

$("#id_a_element_2").hover(
         function () {
         },
         function () {    
         }
   );

$("#id_a_element_3").hover(
         function () {
         },
         function () {    
         }
   );

$("#id_a_element_4").hover(
         function () {
         },
         function () {    
         }
   );
```

Правильно ли будет использовать первый вариант? Не противоречит ли он высшим законам силы природы?

Comment: а если элементов будет 1000, представьте какой длины будет код из второго варианта, а так абсолютно все равно как вешать обработчик, результат будет один

Comment: У меня встречный вопрос... а почему используется запись `id_a_element_1`, `id_a_element_2` и т.д.... если проще сделать данным элементам `class`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Проще с точки зрения производительности? Дело в том что их нужно уникально идентифицировать. Но, в первом примере,так идентифицировать мы не можем как во втором варианте, поэтому к первому варианту мы применяем  фильтр, который я сюда не вставил. Фильтр помогает идентифицировать элемент.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов проще в плане "никаких извращенских манипуляций".... согласитесь написать `$(".elementsForHover").hover()` гораздо проще,чем циклы с непонятным поиском городить или миллионы строк с идентификаторами......между прочим в цикле строка `$arr[$i_nav] = $nav_conteiner.children('li').children('a').eq($i_nav).attr('id', 'id_nav' + $i_nav);` совсем бессмысленна.. так как можно просто написать `$('#id_a_element_' + i).hover();` если по порядку цикл...или сделать просто `find` один раз, а потом также через `foerach` опять же написать `$('#id_a_element_' + i).hover();`.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский По большому счету использовать `class` и использовать как в примере for, где мы устанавливаем селектор `hover` , одинаковые операции, это да. Но во втором примере, если мы будем использовать один класс на все элементы, для установки селектора `hover`, нам придется еще писать фильтр что бы идентифицировать элемент.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов `hover` - это **НЕ** селектор... `#` - селектор.... и `.` - селектор........какой фильтр для идентификации? `$("#id_a_element_3")` и есть эта самая идентификация объекта по его уникальному (масло масленое) идентификатору....вы кажется мало еще знаете о селекторах и как идентифицировать элементы на странице

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Как не селектор?  вот - http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Например выражение $('div') осуществит поиск всех div-элементов на странице, $('.className') найдет все элементы с классом className и т. д. В данном примере селекторами являются строки 'div' и '.className', а $( ) — это функция, которая осуществляет поиск элементов по заданному селектору (а так же имеет массу других возможностей).

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Селекторы псевдоклассов

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Вы меня не правильно поняли. Фильтр нужно применять в первом примере а не во втором я же написал это. И я писал именно про ID  а не про КЛАСС. А вы написали про  ID $("#id_a_element_3")

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов короч вы меня не поняли и ладно........ `Как не селектор? вот - http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B` - вот и найдите мне там селектор `hover` удивите меня

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  Та пища которая была съедобна, я её уже съел, спасибо вам за это. Остальное я оставил. Пускай оно покоиться с миром, и не беспокоит  нас с вами, как и  других людей. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если выбирать из двух представленных вариантов, то решение с циклом будет удобнее. Но вообще плодить такое количество обработчиков, когда можно создать один, повесив его на общий для всех необходимых элементов класс, не самое удачное решение.